# VBA scripts not running in Outlook 2007

Tags: vba, loading, outlook-2007

I placed a new VBA script to autobcc myself on every message that is sent through Outlook 2007. The code seems to work great. The problem I have is that every time I restart my computer and load Outlook 2007 the code is not engaged until after I open the VBA editor. It will continue to run properly this way even if I close the editor. Do I have to open and then close the VBA editor every time I open Outlook 2007? Is there a way to force VBA scripts to engage when Outlook 2007 is opened and loaded?

Here is the script I'm using:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                                 Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim res As Integer
    Dim strBcc As String
    On Error Resume Next

    ' #### USER OPTIONS ####
    ' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address
    ' or resolvable to a name in the address book
    strBcc = "email@domain.com"

    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC
    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                "Do you want to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                "Could Not Resolve Bcc")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

    Set objRecip = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems the issue comes from your Trust Center settings. You need to adjust the Macro Security settings in Outlook. Try to set it to the lowest level.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your macro security settings in Outlook. If they are set to "*No warnings and disable all macros*" (the highest security setting), you can still run code directly from the VBA IDE, but because macros are disabled, your code won't run from Outlook's explorer when the VBA IDE is not open.

If your security setting is low enough to allow macros to run, then the next step is to try and nail down where the error occurs. Start by removing the "*On Error Resume Next*" line (that's a horrible thing to do, BTW), and replace it with "*On Error GoTo ErrTrap*".

Then, write a subroutine called **ErrTrap()** to process the error. You can use the *Err.Number* and *Err.Description* objects to feed a meaningful error message into a MessageBox. Post the message here, and we may be able to help you troubleshoot from there.

Cheers,

-=Cameron